# Cursor change during Draggable function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a pipeline like project game in JS & JQuery. I would like to know if anyone know how to change the cursor from "open hand" to "close hand" when the player hold a block with throught the JQuery draggable function?

Have a great day,

Yours faithfully,

I am kinda new at JS and JQuery and at the moment I didn't even find the "close hand" cursor in a library.

Comment: Have you tried adding a class with `cursor` prop to it when dragging happens. [CSS cursor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor).

Answer (score 0):

try below code to open and close hand for drag and drop , cursor : grabbing means close hand and grab means open hand in css and using jquery apply css like below

```
$(".element").on("mousedown touchstart", function(e) {
    $(this).css('cursor','grabbing');
})

$(".element").on("mouseup touchend", function(e) {
    $(this).css('cursor','grab');
})
```